# Page limitation AjaxPagingNavigator?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

When using the wicket paging support for DataView. -> AjaxPagingNavigator

How is it possible to limit the number of pages?

For example :

First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 Next Last

Should be limited to 10 pages max... (First 5 and last 5)

First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 ... 14 15 16 17 18 Next Last

Any idea?
Is it supported by default?
If not... How can I change it?

Thx
Koen

Answer (score 3):

PagingNavigation supports a view size which is 10 by default.

If you want to display the first 5 and last 5, you'll have to roll your own navigation implementation, see AjaxPagingNavigator#newNavigation().